# Monotony of a continuous function with a Jensen-like property

Tags: continuity, monotone-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that for any $a<b$ we have
$$\min\{f(a),f(b)\}\leq f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\leq \max \{f(a),f(b)\}.$$
Prove that $f$ is monotonic.

I have tried to substitute $a,b$ with $\frac{a+b}{2}$ etc., intending to apply some density result of the corresponding elements/fractions in $[a,b]$, with no success yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let $a<b$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with $f(a)\neq f(b)$ (indeed otherwise $f$ is constant). Suppose wlog $f(a) < f(b)$. Then as you say, repeatedly substituting into the given you can show that
$$ f(x) \leq f(y) $$
for all $x<y$ in $[a,b]$ which are dyadic rational combinations of $a,b$. Explicitly, note that the assumption $f(a)<f(b)$ and the given imply
$$ f(a) \leq f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) \leq f(b).$$
Repeat on each subinterval $[a,(a+b)/2]$ , $[(a+b)/2, b]$ and induct to reach all dyadic rational combinations of $a,b$.

By continuity extend to $f(x)\leq f(y)$ for all $x<y$ in $[a,b]$.

There are still some details to keep track of to finish the proof:

Let $[a,b] \subset [c,d] $. Then we claim $f(c)\leq f(d)$. Indeed, otherwise $f(c)>f(d)$ and turn the above argument around to deduce $f(a) \geq f(b)$, a contradiction. And then, again as above, deduce $f$ is increasing on $[c,d]$. Since $c,d$ are arbitrary get that $f$ is increasing on $\mathbb{R}
$.